# Trying to tee inside bash script works on RHEL 6.7 but not on RHEL 6.8

Tags: bash, shell, exec, rhel, tee

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec &> >(tee -a /tmp/file1.log)
echo "1"
echo "2"
echo "3"
```

It runs on a RHEL 6.7 host and what it does is to print 1 2 3 to both stdout and /tmp/file1.log file; Then it terminates the script.

Running the same script on RHEL 6.8 causes a slightly different behavior. It continues to print the output to stdout and to the file, but the script does not terminate. It remains waiting for an input. I have tried to put an "exit 0" at the end of the script but it didn't solve the problem.

bash (4.1.2) and tee (8.4) versions are the same between hosts.

How can I manage the script to terminate instead of remain waiting?

EDIT

Here is the output of `echo $BASHOPTS`
`checkwinsize:cmdhist:expand_aliases:extquote:force_fignore:hostcomplete:interactive_comments:login_shell:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath`

Comment: are the shell options also the same between them? `shopt` lists the shell options. Special shell variables may have an effect too, IGNOREEOF comes to mind but that's usually for interactive shells. `man bash` and find section on Shell Variables for a list.

Comment: Is the script executing `bash` on both hosts?  Perhaps the 6.8 host is running a shell that treats `&>` differently than bash.  (The behavior of that syntax is not well specified, and different shells treat it differently.)

Comment: @strobelight I didn't know about shell options, but I compared the output of shopt and it is the same on both hosts.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I have put `#!/bin/bash` on both scripts to be sure that they are both running under bash. The differente behaviors continue, unfortunatelly.

Comment: perhaps it's simply a race condition.  Try `./yourscript; date` or add a `sleep 10` on a line after the exec line.